# Get the user id list from the beginning of the month

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

Im trying to get the user_id list of all the users that purchased in the last month and never purchased before that, i tried using DATE_TRUNC but it shows no data. any idea?

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
FROM `gcommerce-analytics-prod.grouponi_groupon.tb_orders`
WHERE cast(on_date_ts AS DATE) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() 
  AND DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),month) 
  AND user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
    FROM `gcommerce-analytics-prod.grouponi_groupon.tb_orders` 
    WHERE cast(on_date_ts AS DATE) > '2010-01-01'
      AND cast(on_date_ts AS DATE) < DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), month)
  )
```

Comment: *WHERE cast(on_date_ts AS DATE) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),month)*  will always return **false**.  put earlier day first like *BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),month) AND CURRENT_DATE()*

Comment: Your date filters are all funky. For example `BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),month)` .  Today that would mean `between '2022-10-26' and '2022-10-01'`.  That's not going to work.  If you want current month, try `date_trunc(on_date_ts) = date_trunc(current_date())`.

Comment: So how would you do a BETWEEN the beginning of this month and the end of last month of last year, for example between 30.9.21 and 1.10.22?

Comment: It's always the smallest date first, and then the greatest. So in the example above: `your_date_field between '2021-09-30' and '2022-10-01'`

Comment: I know but I want to make it a general calculation and not a specific one, which means that next month it will check between 2021-10-30 and 2022-11-01 etc. can you check 
the queries in my new post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211006/can-you-confirm-my-dates-calculations-please